# Creating Orange table from numpy array

Tags: numpy-ndarray, orange

I am trying to create an Orange table manually and am having some issues.

My code:

```
new_domain = Domain([
    ContinuousVariable("NAME"),
    ContinuousVariable("AGE"),
    DiscreteVariable("BLOOD TYPE", list(["A+", "A-", "B+", "B-", "AB+", "AB-", "O+", "O-"]))
    ])

data = np.array([
    ["Joe", "25", "B-"],
    ["Marc", "30", "AB+"],
    ["Martin", "28", "O-"]
    ], dtype=object)


orangeTable = Table.from_numpy(new_domain, X=data)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Joe'
```

I don't understand why it try this conversion, what is wrong?
I just begin so not everything is clear at this point ...

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you everything you need to know:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Joe'

The problem is that numpy arrays can *only* contain floating point (numeric) values inside of them. Here, you are tying to include non-numeric (string) values into your array.

If you would like to create a "matrix" like object like the one you have above, that includes string data types and numbers, you will need to construct a **Pandas Data Frame** instead.